# How do I properly use $el and .remove() in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm still confused by this. The common paradigm I see emerge is...

```
view.render()
```

With render set to

```
function () { this.$el.html( this.template() ) }
```

How does this behavior mesh with remove? This renders the view.. but then logically you'll call `.remove()` to unbind the events and ditch it.. If you use that though, you've ditched the parent container ($el), and can't re-render. The docs need to be explicit then that the convention is to not `this.$el.html( this.template() )`, but to render the template by calling `.html()` on some non-el parent element. You can either call .render() using the views own $el and also use `.remove()`.

How does these two work together?

Comment: Also look at [backbone.marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) which has a lot of things out of the box for you and your issue. It's manage things like removing elements/unbinding events/redrawing/.... If you forced to use only backbone, you can see which approach they use for your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice I see is slightly different. Leave the `el` property off entirely -- let backbone create its own element. The `render` method should look like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(some_data_from_somewhere));
    return this;
}
```

and then you call `render` from the router, thusly:

```
some_container.append(view.render().el)
```

If you do it this way, then the default `remove` implementation:

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

starts to make more sense. The view created and has sole control of its `el` so it makes perfect sense for the view to destroy the `el` when it is being destroyed. The view's owner creates the view and adds it to the page; then later, the view's owner destroys the view (by calling `remove`) when the owner is done with it. This approach makes the view nicely self-contained.

Of course, if your view is expecting to bind to an existing `el` or have someone give it an `el` when it is created, then you're going to have to provide a custom `remove` to unbind DOM events (by calling `this.undelegateEvents()` presumably), remove the contents of `this.el` (but not `el` itself), etc. Similarly, if your view has child views then you'd provide a `remove` that would call `remove` on all the children before cleaning itself up.

Comment: This should be in the docs. This is *exactly* what I'm looking for. Thanks. I'm not sure what I missed but I've read two books and the official docs, and I don't see anyone saying *Also, you let the view create and own its own el.* or, `some_container.append(view.render().el)` google for `this.$el.html( this.template() )` -- a lot of confusion is out there.

Comment: Are you calling `some_container.append(view.render().el)` in the view, or router?

Comment: This actually doesn't work. You can't bind events to an el that doesn't exist on instantion.

Comment: The `append(view.render().el)` call would normally be a in a router or a parent view, generally whatever says `v = new View` would also do the `append(v.render().el)`. And this certainly does work, Backbone will bind the view's `events` to the view's `el` properly when the view creates its own `el`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Lt22x7qu/

Comment: And `this.$el.html(this.template())` is fine as that just puts things *inside* the `el`, it has nothing at all to do with *creating* the `el`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your questions; but I think if you look at the sections titled:

Decouple Views from other DOM elements

and

Cleaning Up: Avoiding Memory Leaks and Ghost Views

form the following link, then you might just find the answer that you were looking for.

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/

It was only until recently that I started adding my view to the DOM from outside of the view itself meaning I don't pass in an el: when creating the view. I just have he view render the DOM element from within the view to memory and call render().$el from the calling code to render the view just like the article states.